# JPanel filling whole window

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel

I'm trying to make chess in java, but I'm stuck on the panel's size and location. When I try to change any of them, it does nothing and I don't know why. Could someone explain it to me?

```
package Chess;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class Window extends Component{
    public void addChessWindow() {
        JFrame chessWindow = new JFrame("Chess");
        chessWindow.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        chessWindow.setResizable(false);
        chessWindow.setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
        chessWindow.setUndecorated(true);
        chessWindow.setBackground(Color.decode("#4D6713"));
        chessWindow.setVisible(true);
        
        JPanel field = new JPanel();
        field.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        field.setBounds(30,15,2,1);
        chessWindow.add(field);
    }
}
```

Note: everything starts in the `main` method.

Comment: Read the Swing tutorial on [Layout Managers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html). The working examples from the tutorial will: 1) show you how to use layout managers 2) better practices for the structure of your class to create a GUI. Keep a link to the tutorial handy for all Swing basics.

Answer (score -2):

I think you could do something like this:

```
chessWindow.add(field, BorderLayout.CENTER);
```

Comment: (1-) This is what the code is already doing. By default BorderLayout.CENTER is used if you don't specify another constraint.